# My cursor doesn't stay in the window when scaling

Tags: 3d-view, customization

It used to be that my cursor would teleport to the other end of the window I was scaling or moving something. Is there a setting that I could have toggled that disabled this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable or disable the behaviour in the User Preferences(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>), Input tab, under Mouse section. It's called Continuous Grab.

[image]

Comment: Now *that's* an arrow!

Comment: Thank you! That's my favorite kind of arrow. Just the right amount of way too much.

Comment: Problem: I'm still experiencing the problem (cursor teleporting to the other side) on the latest mac OS with M1chip (arm64). Solution: Disabling the continuous grab solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I should say there isn't. Use <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> keys to avoid it. Also, the keys allow more precision. Like <kbd>S</kbd> *>* <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: That is not correct.